# JPanel won't work or any of his methods when adding component

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to add a component to `JPanel` but when i do the methods in the `JPanel` doesn't getting called or simply won't work.

What I'm trying to do is take an existing image and draw on that image.

Here's some code to begin with:

```
drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel(MainActivity.this);
drawPanel.add(component);
MyListener alpha = new MyListener(MainActivity.this);
drawPanel.addMouseMotionListener(alpha);
drawPanel.addMouseListener(alpha);
mframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
mframe.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
```

DrawPanel Class:

```
private class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MainActivity drawingTest;

    public MyDrawPanel(MainActivity drawingTest) {
        this.drawingTest = drawingTest;
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 1; i < drawingTest.getPoints().size(); i++) {
            Point p1 = drawingTest.getPoints().get(i - 1);
            Point p2 = drawingTest.getPoints().get(i);
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }
    }
}
```

MyListener class:

```
private class MyListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

    private MainActivity drawingTest;

    public MyListener(MainActivity drawingTest) {
        this.drawingTest = drawingTest;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        drawingTest.setPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
        drawingTest.getDrawingPanel().repaint();
        System.out.println("DRAWING : ");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        drawingTest.resetPoints();
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.paintComponent(g)` ...

Comment: from the question i feel that your `MyDrawPanel` is a painting canvas. So why are you adding components to that? Also in the code above you have added components first and then initialised the `drawPanel` variable. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes basically what I'm trying to do is Let's say add an image and then draw on that image.

Comment: why are you not using `g.drawImage` method in `paintComponent` method?

Comment: What are `MainActivity` and `component`? Consider providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can run the code ourselves and see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
mframe.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
// what you forgot
mframe.getContentPane().revalidate();
mframe.getContentPane().repaint();
```